# How to convert polygon coordinates to rectangle(yolo format) for an image labelling?

Tags: parsing, ocr, yolo, image-recognition

I am trying to read water meter reading through OCR, however, my first step is to find ROI. I found a dataset from Kaggle with the labeled data for the ROI. But they are not in rectangles, rather in a polygon shape, some with 5 points, and some with 8 depending on the image. How do I convert this to yolo format?
For example:

`file name | value | coordinates`

```
id_53_value_595_825.jpg 595.825 {'type': 'polygon', 'data': [{'x': 0.30788, 'y': 0.30207}, {'x': 0.30676, 'y': 0.32731}, {'x': 0.53501, 'y': 0.33068}, {'x': 0.53445, 'y': 0.33699}, {'x': 0.56529, 'y': 0.33741}, {'x': 0.56697, 'y': 0.29786}, {'x': 0.53501, 'y': 0.29786}, {'x': 0.53445, 'y': 0.30417}]}

id_553_value_65_475.jpg 65.475 {'type': 'polygon', 'data': [{'x': 0.26133, 'y': 0.24071}, {'x': 0.31405, 'y': 0.23473}, {'x': 0.31741, 'y': 0.26688}, {'x': 0.30676, 'y': 0.26763}, {'x': 0.33985, 'y': 0.60851}, {'x': 0.29386, 'y': 0.61449}]}

id_407_value_21_86.jpg 21.86 {'type': 'polygon', 'data': [{'x': 0.27545, 'y': 0.19134}, {'x': 0.37483, 'y': 0.18282}, {'x': 0.38935, 'y': 0.76071}, {'x': 0.28185, 'y': 0.76613}]}
```

I understood that for yolo format, I need to get xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax so that i can calculate the width and height but i have trouble with parsing the data. Could anyone help?

Thank you.

Edit: Finally, it worked out. Incase anyone is struggling with converting csv file to yolo format from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tapakah68/yandextoloka-water-meters-dataset,
here is my code snipet to just create text files for each image.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import json
import ast
def converttoyolo(csv_file):
  df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
  l_csv = len(df)
  for i in range(l_csv):
    df_row = df.iloc[i]  #get each row
    
    df_ = df_row['photo_name']  #image column 
    df__ = df_.split('.')  #to get name for text file

    df_new = df_row['location']  #start of gettinf coordinates access
    df_dict = ast.literal_eval(df_new)  #str to dict
    df__dict = json.dumps(df_dict, indent = 4)
    df_dict__ = json.loads(df__dict)
    
    convertedDict = df_dict__
    length = len(convertedDict['data'])
    x = []
    y = []
    for j in range(length):  #put each x and y for each row in seperate array
      x.append(convertedDict['data'][j]['x'])
      y.append(convertedDict['data'][j]['y'])

    max_x = max(x)
    max_y = max(y)  #yolo conversion, check answer below
    min_x = min(x)
    min_y = min(y)

    width = max_x - min_x
    height = max_y - min_y 
    center_x = min_x + (width/2)
    center_y = min_y + (height/2)

    def filename(file):   #put in text files
      with open(file+".txt", "w") as file:
        
         file.write(str(width)+','+str(height)+','+ ...
         str(center_y)+','+str(center_y))
    
    filename('/content/drive/MyDrive/yolo/custom_data/jpeg/'+df__[0]) 
    
converttoyolo(csv_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a contour (a list of points) for each shape.
Once you have that, then call `cv::boundingRect()` to turn each contour into a a single bounding rectangle.
Once you have the rectangle, then you you can figure out X, Y, W, and H.
But since YOLO format is CX and CY -- not X and Y -- then you need to do:

```
CX = X + W/2.0
CY = Y + H/2.0
```

Lastly, you must normalize all 4 values.  The YOLO format is space delimited, and the first value is the integer class ID.  So if "dog" is your 2nd class (thus id #1 since it is zero-based), then you'd output:

```
1 0.234 0.456 0.123 0.111
```

...where the 4 coordinates are:

```
CX / image width
CY / image height
W / image width
H / image height
```

If you want more examples of the math, see the Darknet/YOLO FAQ:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/darknet_faq/#darknet_annotations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But now, the first problem is extracting data from the excel cells. When I copied the value from each cell, it works, because they are dictionaries so I can easily convert them to JSON and get access to each value. However, when I directly extract them from a CSV file, since they are in string form, there are errors to access string integers.

Answer (score 0):

The way I work with pictures:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

img = Image.open(<path>)
w, h = img.size

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.load_default()

center_x = w * bbox_xc
center_y = h * bbox_cy

rect_width = w * bbox_w
rect_height = h * bbox_h

left = center_x - rect_width // 2
top = center_y - rect_height // 2
right = center_x + rect_width // 2
bottom = center_y + rect_height // 2

draw.rectangle([left, top, right, bottom], outline='blue', width=1)
draw.text((center_x, center_y), f'title', fill="white", font=font)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**