# How to covert a .CSV to yolo format?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, yolo, yolov5, yolov7

```
class,image_path,name,xmax,xmin,ymax,ymin
3.0,4a48c42c9579ec0399e6c5a3e825e765.jpg,GARBAGE,797.0,701.0,262.0,211.0
3.0,4a48c42c9579ec0399e6c5a3e825e765.jpg,GARBAGE,932.0,786.0,329.0,238.0
3.0,4a48c42c9579ec0399e6c5a3e825e765.jpg,GARBAGE,736.0,657.0,275.0,229.0
7.0,ea906a663da6321bcef78be4b7d1afff.jpg,BAD_BILLBOARD,986.0,786.0,136.0,0.0
8.0,1c7d48005a12d1b19261b8e71df7cafe.jpg,SAND_ON_ROAD,667.0,549.0,228.0,179.0
8.0,1c7d48005a12d1b19261b8e71df7cafe.jpg,SAND_ON_ROAD,799.0,628.0,238.0,176.0
```

How to covert above .CSV file to yolo format and through which platform?

I am a beginner and I want to convert above .csv file to yolo format.

I found below link for reference but still not able to solve the problem.

Reference solution : [How to convert polygon coordinates to rectangle(yolo format) for an image labelling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797274/how-to-convert-polygon-coordinates-to-rectangleyolo-format-for-an-image-labell)

I am not getting how to integrate the above piece of code (provided in the link) with my .csv file to convert it into the YOLO Format.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Roboflow** for this purpose. It can automatically convert annotations into various formats. visit: https://app.roboflow.com/